# Does anyone know where to find Enthought NumPy binaries for IronPython?

Tags: numpy, ironpython, enthought

A couple of years ago, Enthought decided to undertake the herculean task of rebuilding NumPy to work well with IronPython. Working binaries were hosted at the following location for a while:
https://store.enthought.com/repo/.iron/

However, since the end of 2014 it seems like the above has become a dead link. While many users reported compatibility issues with these outdated binaries, they remain the only way to actually interop with NumPy at all from IronPython.

I myself had a copy of these binaries for a while, but have since lost track of them unfortunately... Does anyone by any chance know where they can be found? I'm hoping they have not vanished off the face of the Internets...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is still alive. You need a (free) Enthought login to access it.
https://store.enthought.com/accounts/login/

Comment: That's true, I totally missed that! It seems like the bootstrapper doesn't work anymore because of authentication issues. Probably also due to permission changes on the link... do you also know of a way around it?

Comment: Got it, turns out you can setup a local repository in config.py. Thanks!